# Which Pokemon are easy to turn into "medalists"?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I'm trying to have one of my Pokemon win all of the Pokethlon events, but this is naturally not such a simple matter since most Pokemon are only strong in certain areas.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone could point me to Pokemon which are good "Medalist" candidates, with or without the use of Aprijuice. If Aprijuice is involved, I'd be glad if you could specify the apricorn mix used to make it.

Thanks.

Comment: only applies to heart-gold / soul-silver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's entirely possible to have 2 Pokemon "carry" a third weaker Pokemon in the events that he's not ideal for, throughout pretty much every event.

Second, if I'm not mistaken, you can change the build of a Pokemon using Aprijuice between events, so that you can customize it for the specific events you want to go.  It's not like EVs where they are permanent.  I'm not positive on this, however.

That said, I think Ditto would be a good choice: http://www.psypokes.com/dex/psydex/132/stats

Comment: First bit of advice makes a lot of sense really. I guess I'll go for that.
Regarding Ditto, I'm aware he has very high potential stats, but most events require two stats to be rather high, and Ditto's base stats are rather low.
If you know of an Aprijuice mix that can significantly raise two stats, I'd love to hear about it, as my mixing attempts have been rather poor so far.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pokémon_by_performance_stats) on Bulbapedia allows you to order Pokemon by Pokeathalon stats. The Pokemon that can potentially have 5 stars in every stat are Ditto, Mew, Sunkern, Giratina (Origin Forme), and Arceus, so theoretically they are the easiest to turn into medalists.

[This other page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Performance) on Bulbapedia shows a chart explaining how the nature of the Pokemon can cause its stats to fluctuate; this causes the big and small stars that you see when you view a Pokemon's stats.

Finally, [this page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Apriblender) explains the mechanics behind blending Apricorns.

Comment: Hmm, are accented characters a limit of hyperlinking on the SE websites? The preview seems to show the hyperlink going to the "é" in Pokémon, and then just plain text after.

Comment: I fixed the link, just another htmlentities case.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think that Ditto and Sunkern are two of the hardest to turn into medalist Pokemon because you need 5 different kinds of good Aprijuice, and most events need more than one stat.

I think that Pokemon with balanced stats like Mareep and it's Evolutions are better. I'd look through your boxes for something with about a 3 on most stats and try that.

Like Strix said, if one Pokemon is bad in one area, use other Pokemon to help balance it out. Any Pokemon can be a medalist. I have a Slowpoke with a speed medal. :p

Comment: that would make him in a notsoslowpoke

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the evolved form of Cyndaquil, Quilava, is the best. I completed all 5 Pokeathlon events in a piece of cake with Quilava, which I called Red. If you didn't pick cyndaquil as your starter Pokemon, I suggest you start all over! D: just kidding you dont need to start over.